# Predicting data via regression model and storing in a vector

Tags: r

Apologies for what is probably a very basic question.

I have created a linear model for a massive meteorological dataset using multiple regression. My goal is to use that model to "predict" data during a certain period using predictors 1, 2 and 3. I will then compare those predicted data to the observed data for that period.

My approach thus far has been to create a new vector for the predicted values and loop through the vector, creating predicted values based on the extracted coefficients of the linear model. Then, I will simply subtract the predicted values from the observed values. For some reason, this approach results in the new predicted vector being NULL. Any idea how I could approach this?

A sample is below. "data" refers to the dataset containing the predictors.

```
     coef <- coefficients(multipleRegressionModel)

    predictedValues=c()

    for(i in 1:length(data$timePeriod)){
      predictedValues[i] = append(predictedValues, data$coef[1]+data$predictor1[i]*data$coef[2]+data$predictor2[i]*data$coef[3]+
      data$predictor3[i]*data$coef[4])
    }

diff=c()
diff=observedValues - predictedValues
```

Comment: Why do you loop? Just do `predict(multipleRegressionModel, newdata = data)`. Also, do not grow an object in a loop, i.e., do not use `append`. That's extremely slow.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the predict function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making this more difficult than it needs to be. R has a `predict()` function that does all of this for you. If you had a sample `data.frame` like so:

```
set.seed(26) 

mydf = data.frame (a=1:20 , b = rnorm(20), 
                   c = 1:20 + runif(20,2,3)*runif(20, 2, 3),
                   d = 1:20 + rpois(20,5)*runif(1:20)*sin(1:20))
```

And you wanted to train on some rows, and test on the others

```
trainRows<-sample(1:20, 16)
mydf.train<-mydf[trainRows,]
mydf.test<-mydf[-trainRows,]
```

Then fit the model and predict

```
model<-lm(a~b+c+d, data = mydf.train)
summary(model)  #gives info about your model. 

mydf.test$pred<-predict(model1, newdata = mydf.test)

MSE<-mean((mydf.test$pred-mydf.test$a)^2) #calculate mean squared error
MSE
#[1] 0.06321
```

View the predictions with `mydf.test$pred`

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the predict function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using a `glm` on the `mtcars` data.

```
Line<- #setting up the linear model function
function (train_dat, test_dat, variables, y_var, family = "gaussian") 
{
  fm <- as.formula(paste(y_var, " ~", paste(variables, collapse = "+"))) #formula
  glm1 <- glm(fm, data = train_dat, family = family) #run the model
  pred <- predict(glm1, newdata = test_dat) #predict the model
}

data(mtcars)
y_var<-'mpg'
x_vars<-setdiff(names(mtcars),y_var)

mtcars[,'linear_prediction']<-Line(mtcars,mtcars,x_vars,y_var)

head(mtcars)

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb linear_prediction
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4          22.59951
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4          22.11189
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1          26.25064
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1          21.23740
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2          17.69343
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1          20.38304
```